# How to display all elements not just the visible elements with java

Tags: java, android, automation, appium-android, appium-java

I want to get all names from settings menu:
https://app.screencast.com/AdssamooNLZbm?conversation=QUFAp0MrtNKXgm68k42Gfy&tab=Details

https://app.screencast.com/J4VoylbceDuca?conversation=Fodt4TO4fN1IVYW4zb9MKH&tab=Details

https://app.screencast.com/U0fnubCAhMjfW?conversation=wluK8dBoc2UkS6YRDqta1u&tab=Details

```
   
   public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
               
       DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
       dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "Appium");   
       dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Redmi Note 9 Pro");     
       dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");    
       dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "12.0");    
       dc.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.settings");
       dc.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.settings.Settings");
               
       URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");      
       AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(url, dc);

       MobileElement list = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView("+ "new UiSelector().text(\"Services & feedback\"));"));
       Thread.sleep(5000);
       List <WebElement> list2 = driver.findElementsById("android:id/title");
       System.out.println(list2.size());
       
       for (WebElement i : list2) {
           System.out.println(i.getText());
       }
       }
   }
```

```
But my Output: 
10 
Apps
Additional settings
Digital Wellbeing & parental controls
Special features
Mi Account
Google
Accounts & sync
Privacy
Location
Services & feedback
```

Comment: Why did you delete [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75133504) which was virtually the same? Please *don't* do that. It's fine - and encouraged - to edit a question to make it clearer, but deleting and reposting is *not* fine.

Comment: That question was not formatted good and I created a new one better written

Comment: do you wanna print sub-menu?

Comment: @ShilaMosammami no

Comment: "That question was not formatted good" - so all you needed to do was edit it. It's absolutely fine to edit a question; it's *not* fine to go into a delete/repost spiral. Please note that if you build up a large collection of deleted questions, you're more likely to be automatically banned from asking further questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have provided, it only logs the last 10 records shown on the phone.

So firstly a little explanation on this piece of code:

```java
MobileElement list = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView("+ "new UiSelector().text(\"Services & feedback\"));"));
Thread.sleep(5000);
List<WebElement> list2 = driver.findElementsById("android:id/title");
System.out.println(list2.size());
```

It scrolls until you reach `Services & feedback`, waits for 5 seconds, and capture all the elements displaying with the corresponding IDs to your `List`.

So in order to capture all the elements with your provided ID, you probably need to repeat the following processes until you reach your destination:

- Capture current display elements' name
- Perform scrolling

```java
// Create a big ArrayList to store all the Elements display name
ArrayList<String> settingNameList = new ArrayList<>();

// Capture the element displayed on screen first
List<WebElement> list1 = driver.findElementsById("android:id/title");
// Add the captured element's title to big List
for (WebElement item : list1) {
  settingNameList.add(item.getText());
}

// Perform the scrolling after first capturing
MobileElement scrollElement = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView("+ "new UiSelector().text(\"Services & feedback\"));"));
Thread.sleep(5000);

// Capture again on the current displaying screen
List<WebElement> list2 = driver.findElementsById("android:id/title");
// Add the captured element's title to big List
for (WebElement item : list2) {
  settingNameList.add(item.getText());
}

// Then display the Name one by one
for (String settingName : settingNameList) {
  System.out.println(settingName);
}
```

Please note that you have to directly process the captured `WebElement`. If you add `WebElement` into a `List` for later processing, you will very likely to encounter `StaleElementReferenceException`.

Comment: Hello. I've tried your solution but it gives this error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Cached elements 'By.id: android:id/title' do not exist in DOM anymore

Comment: I have modified the code a bit. Please try again if it works. In the previous case, ```StaleElementReferenceException``` should be thrown if the Element DOM does not exist in current showing page. So the above code tries to capture all the setting names in advance.

Comment: Please note for this line: ```ArrayList<String> settingNameList = new ArrayList<>();```

Comment: Yes, it works. One more question: is there a way not to repeat each step after scrolling? Thank you for helping :)

Comment: AFAIK, you can only get the visible items in Appium. So you have to implement your own loop, retrieve all the necessary data from the current visible ```WebElements```, until you reach the bottom of the List.